# Finding single character variable name in VBA using Find(Var_Name)

Tags: vba, excel, search, find

I have a piece of code, that is supposed to replace variable names to match the company testing guidelines.

So far it works quite well - with e few exeptions...
I have a variable named "P" in the given sourcefile (sorry but I didn't pick names and for engineers p as pressure is a valid name...) I need to change it to another Name and move its position in the table. But if it doesn't exist at all, then I put a "Missing" in the table, because for another macro all variablenames need to be present

```
If m_Data.Find(string_to_replace) Is Nothing Then 'string doesn't occur at all
    m_DataStripped.Cells(1, m_col).Value = string_to_replace_with
        For R = 3 To lastRow
           m_DataStripped.Cells(R, m_col).Value = "-- MISSING --"
        Next R
End If
```

This works perfectly fine for longer names, but aparently Find() is looking inside the other values, too.... so everything containing a P is returned (Such as "PPNT").

Is there some Find()- function option to search for "that string exactly"?

I could loop through all 250 fields and check for P but that is cumbersome and inefficient if VBA and Excel support a Find() Method... implementing a decent, fast and efficient searchalgorithm in VBA is (painful) overhead for these excel macros...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using 'xlWhole' in the 'Find' function. This will return only an exact match:

```
If m_Data.Find(string_to_replace, Lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then 'string doesn't occur at all
    m_DataStripped.Cells(1, m_col).Value = string_to_replace_with
        For R = 3 To lastRow
           m_DataStripped.Cells(R, m_col).Value = "-- MISSING --"
        Next R
End If
```